# I want to retrieve only one of each kind

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

```
      Dim sql As String = "select * from privatechat where privaterecipentname = '" & fullname & "'  order by mcount"
```

I got a database that has a list of orders with the same customer FULL NAME. so I only wanted to retrieve that name once although he/she has so many records. If the command finds a row with the same FULL, I wanted it to just proceed to the next that might not be a duplicate. I'm Programming in VB.Net. Thanks!

Comment: i think databases are a bit too much for you right now, it'd be much better if you focused on learning how to develop software without databases - thats a completely independent task. You're currently trying to tackle two goals at once and such a project fails most of the time. Im just sayan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQL you cau use [DISTINCT](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp) keyword to achieve what you want; so your `SELECT` could be something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CustomerFullName FROM OrdersTable
```

Comment: This is correct. But I wanted to select the whole row or at least two columns in that row. Thanks!

Comment: You can use: `SELECT DISTINCT Column1, Column2, Column3 FROM YourTable`

Comment: Works now! But I also wanted to just get the last row of each group. Is that possible?